# How to exclude logging warning messages for IBM Websphere?

Tags: logging, websphere

Is it possible to exclude warning messages for IBM Websphere application server logging if loggin level is setup as INFO (*=info)?

Comment: hopefully you just want to exclude a few specific warning messages and not all warning messages in general?  If you are on WebSphere Liberty you can exclude messages by msg ID using `com.ibm.ws.logging.hideMessage`.  Not sure if this prop also works for WebSphere traditional or not though.

Comment: I want to exclude all warning messages in general. I want to see only Info.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in any logging framework. Logging levels always include messages that are equal to or more severe than the specified logging level.

Comment: what is the use case for wanting to see only INFO and not any WARN messages? I could understand if there is a finite set of noisy warning messages that you want to keep out of logs, but suppressing all warning messages could hide useful messages that explain problems in the application.

Comment: Yes, there are set of noisy warning messages that I want to keep out of logs. May be excluding by msg ID really will be helpful. Can you suggest the instruction format? E.g. for log message:
[10/8/18 13:05:22:958 EDT] 0003ec61 SRTServletRes W    bla-bla-bla
Is 0003ec61 message ID?

Comment: @Sergey `0003ec61` is the thread ID. It looks like you're running traditional WAS, so there is no option like in Liberty to exclude particular messages but instead see my answer. What is the message ID where you replaced `bla-bla-bla`?

Comment: @Kevin This is WPS. If to show more info (in bla-bla-bla) I can see two type of log messages: "[10/8/18 13:05:22:958 EDT] 00048ded - 1284544862   W org.some.package.name isSubscriberAutorized 31r84wt80s598plajyg8js85as2 bla-bla-bla" and "[10/8/18 13:05:22:958 EDT] 0003ec61 SRTServletRes W SECJ0483W: bla-bla-bla". Where is messageID there?

Answer (score 2):

By default, WebSphere Application Server has a global log level of `*=info`. This means the following messages are logged: info, audit, warning, severe, and fatal. It is almost always a malpractice to use *=severe, *=fatal, or *=off, because warnings and errors generally occur infrequently and are critical to understanding why problems occurred. It is often a malpractice to use *=warning, because there are many informational messages that are very useful to understanding why problems occurred. If there are repeating messages flooding your logs, then the last resort should be to broadly disable core logging; instead, consider:

1. Open a support ticket with the owner of the message to understand why the message occurs so frequently.
2. Change the log level of the particular logger for those messages (after understanding what they mean in #1). Any log levels specified after the global log level override the log level for that particular logger. For example, if the log configuration is `*=info:com.test.Logger=warning`, then the threshold is only changed for com.test.Logger messages.
3. On WebSphere Liberty, use `com.ibm.ws.logging.hideMessage` to hide particular messages.